# Vb6 Case a to b in Select Case(Switch) Enum

Tags: vb6

I saw this kind of code in vb6.

```
Private Enum enmMain
    STEP_INIT = 1
    STEP_RUN = 2
    STEP_SLEEP = 3
    STEP_SUSPEND = 4
    STEP_ERROR = 5
End Enum

Private mStep As enmMain

Select Case mStep
  Case Is <= enmMain.STEP_RUN
    'Do something
  Case enmMain.STEP_RUN To enmMain.STEP_ERROR 
    'Do something
```

I don't understand this:

```
Case enmMain.STEP_RUN To enmMain.STEP_ERROR
```

If it goes into that case when it meets this condition:
the latest value is STEP_RUN
current value is STEP_ERROR

How does it work?
I am posting on mobile can't write clean.

Answer (score 5):

It means that the case statement will be satisfied by all values of `mStep` that are between 2 and 5, inclusive.

So there is an imprecision in code. Because the value `STEP_RUN` appears in an inclusive test twice (see the `<=` operator). Which behaviour is intended for `STEP_RUN`, the first or the second? You need to figure it out by understanding the program's logic.

Answer (score 3):

Well, [let's read the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa266274%28v=vs.60%29):

> If *testexpression* matches any **Case** *expressionlist* expression, the *statements* following that **Case** clause are executed up to the next **Case** clause, or, for the last clause, up to **End Select**. Control then passes to the statement following **End Select**. If *testexpression* matches an *expressionlist* expression in more than one **Case** clause, only the statements following the first match are executed.

Select Case will run the first block that matches, and the criteria you can use to match are much more flexible than those allowed in many other languages. `Case Is <= enmMain.STEP_RUN` Will run for any value of `mStep` that is less than or equal to 2, and `Case enmMain.STEP_RUN To enmMain.STEP_ERROR` would run for any value between 2 and 5 inclusive.

Now it seems like somebody didn't quite understand what that meant, though, or at least wrote it in a confusing way, because for a value of 2 only the first Case would run, since as the section I quoted says only the first match is executed.

So the end result is that first `'Do something` will run on values of 2 or less, and the second `'Do something` will run on values of 3, 4, or 5.